# HTML form having action as mailto can it work without mail client?

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I have one question whether can we fill data under the below form and send email to address mentioned in mailto without mail client. I mean to say instead of having installed mail apps in system can it be redirected to browser gmail or other personal email tabs

```
<form action="mailto:someemailaddress.com" >
<input>
<input>
```

Comment: No you can not. You will need a mail client to send emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `mailto:` URLs to open in the browser is not possible, no. You need an email client to send emails.